# opencl kernel too many operands

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel, opencl

I made the basic OpenCL example in "OpenCL Programming Guide for Mac" (rev. 2013-08-08). It worked perfect. Then I replaced and added my own code (for optical calcs) but then it crashes, the debugger show "gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "Executing calculate failed");". After some experimentation I now know where the crash happens, It happens inside the kernel in the following lines of code,

```
float M = angle[i];
float K = sqrt(1.0f - M*M);  // program crashes
```

Some experimentations with these lines of code gives various results

Example1

```
float M = angle[i];
float K = sqrt(M*M);  // works perfect
```

Example2

```
float M = angle[i];
float MM = 1.0f - M*M;   // program crash
float K = sqrt(MM);
```

Example3

```
float M = angle[i];
float MM = M*M;
float K = sqrt(1.0f - MM);  // works perfect
```

It seems that when there is more than 2 operands per line, in the kernel code, it crashes. Probably not a hardware issue because APPLE's NBody-demo works (I have a ATI 4850; Xcode 5.1; osx 10.9). I using the recommended libraries with no extra libraries and I have checked the Build-Settings.
Making the program with 2-opernd statements works but is ugly, and i don't understand what happening.

Tommy Landberg, Stockholm, Sweden

Comment: Apple's Opencl implementation is poor, I think this is likely a bug in their compiler.

Comment: Could you please give the value returned on "err" by the OpenCL API? Not the hardcoded message. You could also provided the kernel buildlog, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Tommy, can you try compiling the code without optimizations?  When using clBuildProgram, pass "-cl-opt-disable" and see if that works.  If so, when at least you know it is a bug with their optimization routine and you can write code while getting another system up.

Comment: Is M^2 ever > 1.0f? If so, you're taking the square root of a negative.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem is related to Apple's gcl. The program works fine when using the standard OpenCL functions. It is not a negative square root issue (sharp-sighted Ditermaster:) and it is not related to optimization. Unfortunately i am not skilled enough get a good buildlog-file with gcl. But the error happens when compiling the dispatch-queue block. Tommy